# Why does eclipse say I have no return statement in this method

Tags: java, eclipse, methods, syntax, ide

I wrote a helper method for a class I am doing in java with Eclipse IDE. The code for that method is as follows

```
private foo getfooMonitor(String id)
{
    if(fooList.isEmpty())
    {
        if (Mgr.getValue(Name, ListPath + id) == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for(foo f : fooList)
        {
            if(f.getID().equalsIgnoreCase(id))
            {
                return foo;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

I am curious as to why if the method will be forced to return something, since it has an `if then else` block which has a `return` statement hit no matter what, why eclipse would think I do not have a return statement?

Is this eclipse enforcing some weird syntax because it has trouble parsing the `if then else` block to see the method will be forced to return, or is this a java thing with not allowing a `non void` method to be valid unless it has a return statement as the last line in a method body?

Comment: What do you return if `Mgr.getValue` is not `null`?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis its a helper function, so there is code to handle if the returned value is null from the calling code.

Comment: Which do you think is more likely: that Eclipse is wrong, or that your code is wrong?

Comment: What does the `getfooMonitor` method return if `Mgr.getValue` is not `null`?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis ah gotcha. just noticed that when you pointed it out. Wasn't trying to ask a stupid question or anything was really curious if there was something going on I didn't know of.

Comment: @MattBall I knew it was most likely my code was wrong but thats why I came here. To figure out something to that I didn't know what was up with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not all paths return. If `Mgr.getValue(Name, ListPath + id) == null` returns false then your method doesn't have a return value

Answer (score 1):

Not each execution path has a return value: what if `fooList.isEmpty()`, but `Mgr.getValue(Name, ListPath + id) != null` ? The inner `if` is never entered. The outer `else` is ignored, because the outer `if` was entered. Therefore, the program reaches a state, where the method ends, but nothing is returned.

Sidenote: regarding execution path, the Java compiler is pretty dumb. Take for example the following method:

```
boolean isTrue(boolean value) {
    if (value) {
        return (true);
    }
    if (!value) {
        return (false);
    }
}
```

By the [tertium non datur](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_excluded_middle), either the first or the second `if` is executed. But this code still gives the same compile error. The only way to get this running is to change `if (!value)` to `else` (which - semantically - is the same).

Answer (score 1):

you only have a return statement in the nested if statement in your original if statement. If `Mgr.getValue(Name, ListPath + id) != null` but outside statement is valid, then there is no return statement.

Answer (score 1):

```
private foo getfooMonitor(String id)
{
    if(fooList.isEmpty())
    {
        if (Mgr.getValue(Name, ListPath + id) == null)
        {
            return null;
        } else {
            //this path does not return a value 
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for(foo f : fooList)
        {
            if(f.getID().equalsIgnoreCase(id))
            {
                return foo;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

See the path with no return indicated with a comment.